# Unable to get ng-repeat correctly

Tags: angularjs

Chrome Network shows this when there's no certificate to show:

```
    user_certificates: []
```

I'm trying to show "Add Certificate" button when there's no certificate to show but it's not working. Where am I going wrong?

```
    <div ng-show="users.user_certificates == null">
        <div ng-click="newCertificate.editFlag = !newCertificate.editFlag" ng-init="newCertificate.editFlag=false">
            <span class="btn btn-default">Add Certificate</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

FYI, this is my working code to show when there's certificate:

```
    <div ng-repeat="certificate in user.user_certificates">
        <div ng-hide="certificate.editFlag">
            <strong>{{certificate.title}}</strong><br />
            {{certificate.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try

```
<div ng-show="users.user_certificates.length === 0">
```

Comparing an array to null always return false. That's why your `ng-show` did not work. You can even try `user_certificates.length[index] == null` it will compare the value stored in given index, not compare whole array. You can either use `typeof` to check whether is an array defined or not. Like

```
if(typeof user_certificates.length === "undefined") {
  //Array is not defined
}
```

Comment: thank you. got it working with the first suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

In JS, an empty array does not equate to null, e.g. if you try this in the console:

```
a = [];
a == null
```

You will get false returned.
Equally because of the way objects work in JS, `a == []` will also be false.
What you want is something along the lines of `a.length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a watcher

```
$scope.$watch('user_certificates', function(newVal){
    $scope.hasCerts = !!newVal.length;
});




<div ng-hide="hasCerts">
    <div ng-click="showAddCertForm()">
        <span class="btn btn-default">Add Certificate</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you'd have to use $scope.$watchCollection, as $watch only reacts to 'assiging' - ex. $scope.user_certificates = newValue;